React-pdf failing to load pdf from Url
I am using react-pdf to view pdf in my Next.js web app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf
When I am trying to acces my pdfs that I have on cloud using url, I am getting error: Failed to fetch the PDF.
Precisely: net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
And detials are:
PDFFetchStreamReader    @ pdf.mjs:9529 
getFullReader @ pdf.mjs:9491 
eval @ pdf.mjs:12060 
eval @ pdf.mjs:8562 
#createStreamSink   @ pdf.mjs:8561 
MessageHandler._onComObjOnMessage @ pdf.mjs:8406

where pdf.mjs is ./node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs
I have no idea why this fetch from URL is not working, if I paste the URL into the browser, my pdf is loaded normally (sorry cannot share the URL, its using tokens of my cloud storage)
I am just normally passing the url as:
<PdfViewer file='https://....' /> 
and there is no file fetched.
